# visually customizing Git Status output?

Tags: git, command-line-interface

I was wondering if it was possible, to colorize a specific part of the git status message, specifically:

`your branch is ahead of ... by x commits`

Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) this does not seem to be possible.

The closest you could get to that is to colorize the whole header text as follows:

```
git config --global color.status.header yellow
```

with the outcome being something like this:

[image]

Comment: is there a way to highlight specific parts of the message? Like the number of commits ahead for example.

Comment: No, as stated in my answer above this does not seem to be supported natively in Git.